How can I fix this problem with linking libtiff on Linux
I’m trying to link with libtiff.a (static library) which is in /usr/local/lib
Revised to list entire content of the CMakeLists.txt:
set(PROJECT_NAME DeepSkyStacker)
message("Configuring project: " ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR YES)
SET (CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR ".")

qt_standard_project_setup()

set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

################################################################################
# Source groups
################################################################################
set(Dialogs
    "About.cpp"
    "ExplorerBar.cpp"
)
source_group("Dialogs" FILES ${Dialogs})

set(Dialogs__Processing
    "BezierAdjust.h"
    "processingcontrols.cpp"
    "ProcessingDlg.cpp"
    "ProcessingSettings.h"
    "ProcessingSettingsDlg.cpp"
    "RGBTab.cpp"
    "SavePicture.cpp"
    "StarMaskDlg.cpp"
)
source_group("Dialogs\\Processing" FILES ${Dialogs__Processing})

set(Dialogs__Registering
    "AskRegistering.cpp"
    "RegisterSettings.cpp"
)
source_group("Dialogs\\Registering" FILES ${Dialogs__Registering})

set(Dialogs__Settings
    "AlignmentParameters.cpp"
    "CometStacking.cpp"
    "IntermediateFiles.cpp"
    "OutputTab.cpp"
    "PostCalibration.cpp"
    "RawDDPSettings.cpp"
    "ResultParameters.cpp"
    "StackingParameters.cpp"
    "StackSettings.cpp"
)
source_group("Dialogs\\Settings" FILES ${Dialogs__Settings})

set(Dialogs__Stacking
    "BackgroundOptions.cpp"
    "BatchStacking.cpp"
    "CheckAbove.cpp"
    "DropFilesDlg.cpp"
    "ImageProperties.cpp"
    "picturelist.cpp"
    "RecommendedSettings.cpp"
    "RenameGroup.cpp"
    "SaveEditChanges.cpp"
    "StackingDlg.cpp"
    "StackRecap.cpp"
)
source_group("Dialogs\\Stacking" FILES ${Dialogs__Stacking})

set(Header_Files
    "../DeepSkyStackerKernel/histogram.h"
    "DeepSkyStacker.h"
    "Delaunay.h"
    "dslr.h"
    "DSS-versionhelpers.h"
    "DSS-winapifamily.h"
    "DSS-winpackagefamily.h"
    "lowerdockwidget.cpp"
    "mrulist.h"
    "stdafx.h"
)
source_group("Header Files" FILES ${Header_Files})

set(Source_Files
    "BaseDialog.cpp"
    "DeepSkyStacker.cpp"
    "Delaunay.cpp"
    "editstars.cpp"
    "progressdlg.cpp"
    "selectrect.cpp"
    "toolbar.cpp"
)
source_group("Source Files" FILES ${Source_Files})

set(Ui_Files
    "ui/About.ui"
    "ui/AlignmentParameters.ui"
    "ui/AskRegistering.ui"
    "ui/BackgroundOptions.ui"
    "ui/BatchStacking.ui"
    "ui/CheckAbove.ui"
    "ui/CometStacking.ui"
    "ui/DropFilesDlg.ui"
    "ui/ExplorerBar.ui"
    "ui/ImageProperties.ui"
    "ui/IntermediateFiles.ui"
    "ui/OutputTab.ui"
    "ui/PictureList.ui"
    "ui/PostCalibration.ui"
    "ui/ProcessingControls.ui"
    "ui/ProcessingDlg.ui"
    "ui/ProcessingSettingsDlg.ui"
    "ui/ProgressDlg.ui"
    "ui/RawDDPSettings.ui"
    "ui/RecommendedSettings.ui"
    "ui/RegisterSettings.ui"
    "ui/RenameGroup.ui"
    "ui/ResultParameters.ui"
    "ui/SaveEditChanges.ui"
    "ui/StackingDlg.ui"
    "ui/StackingParameters.ui"
    "ui/StackRecap.ui"
    "ui/StackSettings.ui"
    "ui/StarMaskDlg.ui"
    )
    
source_group("Qt\\ui" FILES ${Ui_Files})

set(i18n_Files
    "i18n/DSS_ca.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_cs.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_de.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_en.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_es.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_fr.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_it.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_ja_JP.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_nl.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_pt_BR.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_ro.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_ru.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_tr.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_zh_CN.ts"
    "i18n/DSS_zh_TW.ts"
    )
    
source_group("Qt\\i18n" FILES ${i18n_Files} "i18n/translations.qrc"
    )

set(Resources
    "Icon.rc"
    "Icon/app.ico"
    "resources.qrc"
    "Version.rc"
    "res/4Corners.bmp"
    "res/4Corners.png"
    "res/asinh.bmp"
    "res/BiasColour.png"
    "res/BiasColour@2x.png"
    "res/BiasCYMG.png"
    "res/BiasCYMG@2x.png"
    "res/BiasGreyscale.png"
    "res/BiasGreyscale@2x.png"
    "res/BiasRGB.png"
    "res/BiasRGB@2x.png"
    "res/bmp00001.bmp"
    "res/brazil.png"
    "res/ButtonComet_Disabled.png"
    "res/ButtonComet_Down.png"
    "res/ButtonComet_Hot.png"
    "res/ButtonComet_Up.png"
    "res/ButtonSave_Disabled.png"
    "res/ButtonSave_Down.png"
    "res/ButtonSave_Hot.png"
    "res/ButtonSave_Up.png"
    "res/ButtonSelect_Disabled.png"
    "res/ButtonSelect_Down.png"
    "res/ButtonSelect_Hot.png"
    "res/ButtonSelect_Up.png"
    "res/ButtonStar_Disabled.png"
    "res/ButtonStar_Down.png"
    "res/ButtonStar_Hot.png"
    "res/ButtonStar_Up.png"
    "res/Calibration_Linear.bmp"
    "res/Calibration_Rational.bmp"
    "res/Catalan.png"
    "res/Comet_Freeze.bmp"
    "res/Comet_Normal.bmp"
    "res/Comet_Trails.bmp"
    "res/cuberoot.bmp"
    "res/CurveMethods.pspimage"
    "res/custommode.bmp"
    "res/Czech.png"
    "res/DarkColour.png"
    "res/DarkColour@2x.png"
    "res/DarkCYMG.png"
    "res/DarkCYMG@2x.png"
    "res/darkfram.ico"
    "res/darkframe.ico"
    "res/DarkGreyscale.png"
    "res/DarkGreyscale@2x.png"
    "res/DarkRGB.png"
    "res/DarkRGB@2x.png"
    "res/Dutch.png"
    "res/FlatColour.png"
    "res/FlatColour@2x.png"
    "res/FlatCYMG.png"
    "res/FlatCYMG@2x.png"
    "res/flatframe.ico"
    "res/FlatGreyscale.png"
    "res/FlatGreyscale@2x.png"
    "res/FlatRGB.png"
    "res/FlatRGB@2x.png"
    "res/GammaOff.bmp"
    "res/GammaOn.bmp"
    "res/German.png"
    "res/hdrdown.bmp"
    "res/hdrup.bmp"
    "res/Heart.png"
    "res/icon1.ico"
    "res/ImageList_CFA_CYMG.bmp"
    "res/ImageList_CFA_RGB.bmp"
    "res/ImageList_Color.bmp"
    "res/ImageList_GrayScale.bmp"
    "res/ImageList_Mask.bmp"
    "res/intersectionmode.bmp"
    "res/Italian.png"
    "res/LightColour.png"
    "res/LightColour@2x.png"
    "res/LightCYMG.png"
    "res/LightCYMG@2x.png"
    "res/lightfra.ico"
    "res/lightframe.ico"
    "res/LightGreyscale.png"
    "res/LightGreyscale@2x.png"
    "res/LightRGB.png"
    "res/LightRGB@2x.png"
    "res/linear.bmp"
    "res/linear_en.bmp"
    "res/linear_fr.bmp"
    "res/log.bmp"
    "res/loglog.bmp"
    "res/logo.png"
    "res/logsqrt.bmp"
    "res/MaskStarShapes.pspimage"
    "res/mosaicmode.bmp"
    "res/normalmode.bmp"
    "res/offsetframe.ico"
    "res/Pattern_BGGR.bmp"
    "res/Pattern_CYGMCYMG.bmp"
    "res/Pattern_GBRG.bmp"
    "res/Pattern_GRBG.bmp"
    "res/Pattern_RGGB.bmp"
    "res/Portugal.png"
    "res/prc.png"
    "res/RGBCalibration_Maximum.bmp"
    "res/RGBCalibration_Middle.bmp"
    "res/RGBCalibration_Minimum.bmp"
    "res/RGBCalibration_None.bmp"
    "res/Romanian.png"
    "res/Russian.png"
    "res/Spanish.png"
    "res/sqrt.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_Bell.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_Cone.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_Cubic.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_Quadratic.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_TruncatedBell.bmp"
    "res/StarShape_TruncatedCone.bmp"
    "res/Taiwan.png"
    "res/Turkish.png"
    )
    
source_group("Resources" FILES ${Resources} )

set(Tools
    "../Tools/imageview.cpp"
    "../Tools/QElidedLabel.cpp"
    "../Tools/QLinearGradientCtrl.cpp"
)
source_group("Tools" FILES ${Tools})

set(ALL_FILES
    ${Dialogs}
    ${Dialogs__Processing}
    ${Dialogs__Registering}
    ${Dialogs__Settings}
    ${Dialogs__Stacking}
    ${Header_Files}
    ${Ui_Files}
    ${i18n_Files} "i18n/translations.qrc"
    ${Resources}
    ${Source_Files}
    ${Tools}
)

################################################################################
# Target
################################################################################
qt_add_executable(DeepSkyStacker ${ALL_FILES})

set_source_files_properties(${i18n_Files}
     PROPERTIES OUTPUT_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/i18n")

qt_add_lrelease(TS_FILES ${i18n_Files})

set_target_properties(DeepSkyStacker PROPERTIES
    INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_RELEASE "TRUE"
)
set_target_properties(DeepSkyStacker PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
    MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
)

################################################################################
# Include directories
################################################################################
target_include_directories(DeepSkyStacker PUBLIC
    .
    ../DeepSkyStackerKernel
    GeneratedFiles/$<CONFIG>
    GeneratedFiles
    ../LibRaw
    ../ZClass
    ../Tools
  )

if(WIN32)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
   ../Zlib
   ../LibTiff
   ../CFitsIO
   ../include
   ../include/exiv2
   ../include/SmtpMime
   "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Leak Detector/include>"
   "$ENV{Boost_1_80_0}"
)
endif()

target_precompile_headers(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
    stdafx.h
    )

################################################################################
# Compile definitions
################################################################################
target_compile_definitions(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
  "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Z_TRACE_DEVELOP>"
  "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:NDEBUG>"
  NOMINMAX
  LIBRAW_NODLL
  _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
  USE_LIBTIFF_STATIC
)

################################################################################
# Compile and link options
################################################################################
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
            /Gm-;
            /Zi
        >
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:
            /Zi;
            /GS-
        >
        -W4 /wd4244 /wd4652 /wd4702 /wd4828 
        -Zc:__cplusplus /openmp:experimental
        /MP;
        /GL-;
        /EHsc
    )
    target_link_options(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
            /PROFILE
        >
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:
            /OPT:ICF
        >
        /DEBUG:FULL;
        /MACHINE:X64;
        /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS;
        /DYNAMICBASE:NO
    )
elseif(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        -mavx -msse4.2
    )
endif()

if(WIN32)
target_link_directories(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:C:/Users/amonra/Documents/GitHub/DSS/libs/Win64/DebugLibs>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:C:/Users/amonra/Documents/GitHub/DSS/libs/Win64/ReleaseLibs>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Leak Detector/lib/Win64>"
    )
endif()

################################################################################
# Dependencies
################################################################################
# Link with other targets.
target_link_libraries(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Widgets
    Qt6::Network
    DeepSkyStackerKernel
    libraw
    ZClass
)
if(WIN32)
target_link_libraries(DeepSkyStacker PRIVATE
    libtiff
)
endif()

if(WIN32)
set(DEBUG_DEPENDENCIES exiv2d zlibstaticd)
set(RELEASE_DEPENDENCIES exiv2 zlibstatic)
else()
set(DEBUG_DEPENDENCIES libtiff.a exiv2 expat libz.a)
set(RELEASE_DEPENDENCIES libtiff.a exiv2 expat libz.a)
endif()

set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEBUG_DEPENDENCIES}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${RELEASE_DEPENDENCIES}>"
    "cfitsio"
)

if(WIN32)
set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES ${ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES}
    user32
    psapi
    htmlhelp
)
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES}")

#
# Force the values of QT_DEPLOY... variables
#
set (QT_DEPLOY_BIN_DIR ".")
set (QT_DEPLOY_LIBEXEC_DIR ".")
set (QT_DEPLOY_LIB_DIR ".")
set (QT_DEPLOY_PLUGINS_DIR ".")

#
# Set options for the deployment script.   The value of:
# 
# --libdir .
# 
# is set to work around a bug in qt_deploy_runtime_dependencies which uses
#
# --libdir bin
# 
# even though QT_DEPLOY_LIB_DIR is set to .
#
set (deploy_tool_options_arg ".")
if(APPLE)
    set(deploy_tool_options_arg "${deploy_tool_options_arg} --hardened-runtime")
elseif(WIN32)
    set(deploy_tool_options_arg "${deploy_tool_options_arg} --pdb")
endif()

# Generate a deployment script to be executed at install time
# App bundles on macOS have an .app suffix
if(APPLE)
    set(executable_path "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:DeepSkyStacker>.app")
else()
    message ("Qt Deploy Bin Dir: " ${QT_DEPLOY_BIN_DIR})
    message ("Qt Deploy Lib Dir: " ${QT_DEPLOY_LIB_DIR})
    message ("Target filename:"  $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:DeepSkyStacker>)
    set(executable_path "${QT_DEPLOY_BIN_DIR}/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:DeepSkyStacker>")
endif()
message ("executable_path: " ${executable_path})
message ("deploy tools options arg: " ${deploy_tool_options_arg})
 qt_generate_deploy_script(
     TARGET DeepSkyStacker
     OUTPUT_SCRIPT deploy_script
     CONTENT "
 qt_deploy_runtime_dependencies(
     EXECUTABLE \"${executable_path}\"
     DEPLOY_TOOL_OPTIONS ${deploy_tool_options_arg}
 )"
 )

INSTALL (TARGETS DeepSkyStacker)
INSTALL (SCRIPT ${deploy_script})

#[=[
if(WIN32)
################################################################################
# Post build events
################################################################################
set (deployment_string
        ${WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE} " --verbose 2 --dir . --plugindir plugins "
        "--compiler-runtime --pdb "
        $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:DeepSkyStacker>
    )
message ("Deployment command: " ${deployment_string})

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
  TARGET DeepSkyStacker
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND
    ${WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE} --verbose 2 --dir . --plugindir plugins
        --compiler-runtime --pdb
        $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:DeepSkyStacker>
       
    )
endif()
#]=]

when I try to link I get:
FAILED: DeepSkyStacker/DeepSkyStacker 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -g  DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/DeepSkyStacker_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/About.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/ExplorerBar.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/processingcontrols.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/ProcessingDlg.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/ProcessingSettingsDlg.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/RGBTab.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/SavePicture.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/StarMaskDlg.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/AskRegistering.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/RegisterSettings.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/AlignmentParameters.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/CometStacking.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/IntermediateFiles.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/OutputTab.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/PostCalibration.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/RawDDPSettings.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/ResultParameters.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/StackingParameters.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/StackSettings.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/BackgroundOptions.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/BatchStacking.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/CheckAbove.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/DropFilesDlg.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/ImageProperties.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/picturelist.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/RecommendedSettings.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/RenameGroup.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/SaveEditChanges.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/StackingDlg.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/StackRecap.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/lowerdockwidget.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/BaseDialog.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/DeepSkyStacker.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/Delaunay.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/editstars.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/progressdlg.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/selectrect.cpp.o DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/toolbar.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/__/Tools/imageview.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/__/Tools/QElidedLabel.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/__/Tools/QLinearGradientCtrl.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/DeepSkyStacker_autogen/O3VI4VFR3H/qrc_translations.cpp.o
DeepSkyStacker/CMakeFiles/DeepSkyStacker.dir/DeepSkyStacker_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_resources.cpp.o
-o DeepSkyStacker/DeepSkyStacker  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib:  DeepSkyStackerKernel/libDeepSkyStackerKernel.a
LibRaw/buildfiles/liblibraw.a  ZClass/libZClass.a  -Wl,-Bstatic  -ltiff  -Wl,-Bdynamic  -lexiv2  -lexpat  -Wl,-Bstatic  -lz
-Wl,-Bdynamic  -lcfitsio  /opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Widgets.so.6.8.0  /opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Gui.so.6.8.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  /opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Network.so.6.8.0
 /opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt6Core.so.6.8.0  -llibtiff  -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/Qt/6.8.0/gcc_64/lib && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtiff: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: note to link with /usr/local/lib/libtiff.a use -l:libtiff.a or rename it to liblibtiff.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I imagine I’ve made a classic beginner’s mistake, but what is it please?
I changed these lines to try to correct the problem:
set(DEBUG_DEPENDENCIES tiff.a exiv2.a expat.a z.a cfitsio.a)
set(RELEASE_DEPENDENCIES tiff.a exiv2.a expat.a z.a cfitsio.a)

and added this:
get_target_property(OUT ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS "Link libraries: " ${OUT})

and the configure step said:
1> [CMake] Configuring project: DeepSkyStacker
1> [CMake] -- Link libraries: Qt6::CoreQt6::CoreQt6::WidgetsQt6::NetworkDeepSkyStackerKernellibrawZClass$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:tiff.aexiv2.aexpat.az.acfitsio.a>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:tiff.aexiv2.aexpat.az.acfitsio.a>

So I have no idea where the -llibtiff came from

Welcome to SO. The error (which, yes, is a classic beginner's error) could only result from a WIN32 build given the
posted portion of CMakeLists.txt, but your build log shows a linux build. You better show us the whole, true CMakeLists.txt
from which you get this error.

BTW, have you read the message immediately after the error? /usr/bin/ld: note to link with /usr/local/lib/libtiff.a use -l:libtiff.a or rename it to liblibtiff.a? It explains how to fix the problem, don't you think so? Or you could note that the command line already contains -ltiff, and remove your linkage.

I added this to my CMakeLists.txt:
get_target_property(OUT ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS "Link libraries: " ${OUT})
and the configure step said:
1> [CMake] Configuring project: DeepSkyStacker
1> [CMake] -- Link libraries: Qt6::CoreQt6::CoreQt6::WidgetsQt6::NetworkDeepSkyStackerKernellibrawZClass$<$CONFIG:Debug:tiff.aexiv2.aexpat.az.acfitsio.a>$<$CONFIG:Release:tiff.aexiv2.aexpat.az.acfitsio.a>
So I have no idea where the -llibtiff came from

/user was a typo

I still do not see how this can be the CMakeLists.txt you
actually built with, from clean, to get the error. Is it still there is
you delete everything from the CMake build directory and rebuild
from scratch?

I have cleared the CMake cache and re-configured with that exact CMakeLists.txt and still get the problen

ARRGGH!
The problem came from the CMakeLists.txt for one of the static libs which contained:
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
libraw
libtiff
ZClass
)
David
